# Python reverse replace

Tags: python

Help with fixing reverse method... (text to numbers, then reverse back, numbers to text)
Below is the full code unedited.

```
chars=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","t","s","u","v","w","x","y","z","!","@","#","$","%","^","&","*","(",")","<",">","?","/","[","]","{","}","-","_","=","+"," "];
numbs1=["01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31","32","33","34","35","36","37","38","39","40","41","42","43","44","45","46","47","48","49"];
rechars1=dict(zip(chars,numbs1));
rechars2=dict(zip(numbs1,chars)); # ??
stringa=raw_input(""); #Letters and symbols only-->encrypt
stringb=''.join(rechars1.get(c,c) for c in stringa);
stringc=''.join(rechars2.get(c,c) for c in stringb); # ??
print "Plain:     ",stringa;
print "Encoded:   ",stringb;
print "Unencoded: ",stringc; #same as stringb??
```

Comment: Reverse what? Please elaborate.

Comment: Semi-colons aren't necessary in Python.

Comment: I know but I prefer them, and in response to your answer below, tried that

Comment: It's impossible to reverse the encoding you gave *if* there was a two digit number in the original string. That two-digit number would not be translated, and therefore you wouldn't be able to tell whether it was an original or one that should be translated back. (For instance, `"a01"` would translate to `"0101"`- that's impossible to translate back, as it could have been any of `"aa"`, `"a01"`, `"01a"`, or `"0101"`.

Comment: It's text-->numbers encrypt. Numbers-->text decrypt. I'll post complete code.

Comment: If you do know that there are no digits in the plaintext, then my below solution (edited since its original posting) will work. ETA: No it won't, I neglected to consider that `"4015"` contains `"01"`. Correcting it. ETA: Corrected.

Comment: Here's a link to my project http://ideone.com/m9TvHu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If* you know that every input character is translated (contains no digits or other characters), then you can reverse it as follows:

```
decipher = dict(zip(numbs1,chars)) 
stringc = ''.join(decipher[stringb[i:i+2]] for i in range(0, len(stringb), 2));
print "Decoded: ", stringc
```

*However*, if a single input character isn't translated, then taking pairs of characters like here won't work (since each pair of characters won't line up to one in the original).

Comment: Added that but error occured it's here http://ideone.com/m9TvHu

Comment: @master101: Typo- changed `[i:i+1]` to `[i:i+2]`

Comment: Sequence has been reversed thanks

Answer (score 1):

The road block is how to break a string such as *'20051920'* into a list of double digits. If you get over that huddle, you can use *rechars2* to translate it back.

My solution employs the regular expression:

```
import re
stringb = '20051920'
print re.findall(r'\d\d', stringb) # ['20', '05', '19', '20']
```

Comment: Naw I edited it so there is a seperate encoder and decoder... And modified it so numbers are supported